# Let a ListView grow in height with animations

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-animation, objectanimator

I have this layout for testing some `Animations`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#0000ff">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_style"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

What I want to achive is that the ListView `list` in the LinearLayout `frame2` should grow to the top of the screen, while the LinearLayout `frame1` shrinks.

This can be done very easily with the `ObjectAnimator` and an `AnimatorSet` like this:

```
ObjectAnimator animframe1 = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(frame1, "bottom", 0);
ObjectAnimator animframe2 = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(frame2, "top", 0);
ObjectAnimator listview = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(list, "bottom", frame2.getBottom());

AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
set.setDuration(1000L);
set.playTogether(animframe1, animframe2, listview);
set.start();
```

What I do is manipulating the `top` and the `bottom` properties of the Views to have the grow/shrink effect.

It works like I want, but with one flaw: While the ListView is growing, the additional items (which are there) aren't visible. The room should be there, but the additional items will only show up if I click the ListView after the animation.

How can I say the ListView that the additional items should be reloaded while the animation runs?

I tried to call `list.invalidate()` in an `AnimationUpdateListener` but without success. If I call `list.requestLayout()` there will be no Animation.

Comment: You can try to play severall shorter animations and on animation end event assign those changes to your objects. It worked for me on android 1.6 where I had to use simple Animation object and at the end of each animation I was applying desired changes.
PS
[Android reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have missed is to set the `height` of the ListView, after the `top` property was modified. Without this the ListView will hold the same old height, which is the reason that no additional items will be shown.

I switched to a ValueAnimator, because there is no need for an additional setter for the `height` in a CustomListView class.

Code is like this:

```
public void animateListHeight() {
    PropertyValuesHolder topList = PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("top", mListView.getTop(), 5);

    ValueAnimator animList = ValueAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(topList);
    animList.setDuration(300L);

    AnimatorUpdateListener listUpdater = new AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            int top = ((Integer)animation.getAnimatedValue("top")).intValue();
            mListView.setTop(top);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams) mListView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = mListView.getBottom() - top;
            mListView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    };

    animList.addUpdateListener(listUpdater);
    animList.start();
}
```